# Finding solution from reading computer language puzzle

Tags: cipher, computer-puzzle, computer-science

How to improve this puzzle?

The task is to find a result, like a number from 1 to 10 from reading and understanding code. For example:

```
result = 0
for num in range(0,11):
    if sympy.isprime(num):
        result = num
        break
print(result)
```

I found that I struggle with reading code, and devised this exercise to improve it. In collaborating with a computer agent, the computer agent can generate puzzles with concepts that I am trying to learn. Concepts like `grid`, `cost to reach cell`, `goal positions` was easy to understand this way. Often the code explicitly contains the answer, which is less challenging, because I know what number I am looking for. Knowing the range of possible values for the answer, increasing the difficulty of the puzzles and working with concepts that I am trying to learn seems to work.

Other examples:

```
result = list(calendar.month_name).index("August")
```

```
today = datetime.date.today()
result = today.day
```

```
result = sympy.isprime(7) + sympy.isprime(9)
```

I wonder how to, for example, change the range of integers meaningfully. Perhaps to connect it with learning mathematical concepts, like fractions, combinatorics, probability. How to weave these values to find into the code? Are there similar, existing puzzles to look into, or methods to learn to improve puzzles?

Comment: Please be more specific. What react improvement do you want, what is your metric of quality? Why are there four examples? Are you hoping we generate more examples of the same type, or improve what is already there?

Comment: Sure. I am looking for any ideas or suggestions for improvement, further reading, etc. I thought this was a terrific idea so I wanted to share it with the world and collaborate to further develop it. It was inspired by a clock reading cognitive exercise. Why is the number of examples important?

Comment: Unfortunately soliciting any and all ideas or suggestions for improvement or suggestions, and especially attempting to set up a collaboration, is not a good question for this site. There must be a focused question with clear metrics to judge the quality/usefulness of an answer; this is not a discussion site.